# Plotting a transfer function in a range of values giving error of plot Not enough input arguments

Tags: matlab

I need to see at which values of `kc` a system is stable and unstable.

The system has the following transfer function:

`(-2Kc)/(s^4+3s^3+4s^2+3s+(1-2kc) )`

[image]

After calculations, for this system to be stable, kc should be in this range of values:

**-1 < Kc < 0.5**

I am using matlab, and added the following to plot the transfer function response for each value of Kc from -2 to 1 with a step of 0.1:

```
syms s kc;

t=(-2*kc)/(s^4+3*s^3+4*s^2+3*s+1-2*kc);

kc=-2:0.1:1;

plot(t)
```

I got the following errors:

> Error using plot Data must be numeric, datetime, duration or an array
>   convertible to double.
>
> Error using plot. Not enough input arguments.

I tried to `step` function but got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that `t` is not a numeric array. `t` is a symbolic object; the `plot` function knows nothing about symbolic objects and can't handle them properly. The second issue is that the `kc` variable definition

```
kc=-2:0.1:1;
```

has no effect because it does not affect the content of the symbolic object `t`.

There is a function `ezplot`, which plots symbolic objects. Also, you need a loop:

```
syms s 

for kc=-2:0.1:1;
    t=(-2*kc)/(s^4+3*s^3+4*s^2+3*s+1-2*kc);
    ezplot(t);
    hold on;
end
```

In order to plot the step response, you can use the Control System Toolbox:

```
for kc=-2:0.25:1;
    h = tf(-2*kc,[1 3 4 3 1-2*kc]);
    step(h,10);
    hold on;
end
```

Comment: Thanks sir..I will try it directly.